# problem when separating an integer and displaying it on a 7-segment display

Tags: c, display, pic

I am simulating a project in Proteus where I show a three-digit number (456) on a 7-segment display, but instead of showing 456 it shows 006.......... the calculations are well done but I can't figure out where is the problem.

here diagram

[7 seg display electric diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aaobR.jpg)

here code

```c
/* Main.c file generated by New Project wizard
 *
 * Created:   mi. ene. 10 2024
 * Processor: PIC16F84A
 * Compiler:  CCS for PIC
 */

#include <16F84a.h>
#fuses NOWDT 
#use delay(clock=4000000) 
#define UNO             0x0C // 00001100
#define DOS         0xB6 // 10110110
#define TRES        0x9E // 10011110
#define CUATRO  0xCC // 11001100
#define CINCO       0xDA // 11011010
#define SEIS            0xFA // 11111010
#define SIETE           0x0E // 00001110
#define OCHO        0xFE // 11111110
#define NUEVE       0xCE // 11001110
#define CERO        0x7E // 01111110
#define ERROR     0b11110010
#define  U 0x1
#define  D 0x2
#define  C 0x4

byte mostrar(int index){
    switch(index) {
        case 0: return CERO;
        case 1: return UNO;
        case 2: return DOS;
        case 3: return TRES;
        case 4: return CUATRO;  
        case 5: return CINCO;
        case 6: return SEIS;
        case 7: return SIETE;
        case 8: return OCHO;
        case 9: return NUEVE;
        default: return ERROR; // Manejar casos no definidos
    }
}

int main (void)
 { 
    set_tris_a(0x00); // Configura todos los pines del Puerto A como salida
    set_tris_b(0x01); // Configura RB0 como entrada, RB1-RB7 como salida
    while(true){
        int numero = 456;
        int unidad = numero % 10;
        int decena = (numero / 10) % 10;
        int centena = numero / 100;       
        
        
        // unidad
        output_a(U);
        output_b(mostrar(unidad));
        delay_ms(10);
        output_a(0);
        
        output_a(D);
        output_b(mostrar(decena));
        delay_ms(10);
        output_a(0);
        
        output_a(C);
        output_b(mostrar(centena));
        delay_ms(10);
        output_a(0);
    }
 }
```

I hope to be able to show the number 456 well on the respective displays and then give it different uses.

Comment: Step 1 would be to rewrite this using arrays and maybe change the language to English, if you expect others to help you with the code.

Answer (score 0):

### Solved.

```
   /* Main.c file generated by New Project wizard
    *
    * Created:   mi. ene. 10 2024
    * Processor: PIC16F84A
    * Compiler:  CCS for PIC
    */
   #include <16F84A.h>
   #use delay(clock=4000000,crystal)//Crystal Externo 4MHz
   #FUSES XT,NOWDT
   Byte CONST display[10]= {0x7E,0x0C,0xB6,0x9E,0xCC,0xDA,0xFA,0x0E,0xFE,0xCE};

   #BYTE PORTB= 6
   #define  U 0x1
   #define  D 0x2
   #define  C 0x4
   int16 numero;
   int unidad,decena,centena;

   //#define ERROR     0b11110010


  int main (void)
    { 
       set_tris_a(0b11111000); // Configura todos los pines del Puerto A como salida
       set_tris_b(0x01); // Configura RB0 como entrada, RB1-RB7 como salida
        while(true){
            numero=456;
            unidad = numero % 10;
            decena = (numero / 10) % 10;
            centena = numero / 100;       
            //unidad
            output_a(U);
            PORTB = (display[unidad]);  
            delay_ms(10);
            output_a(0);        
            //decena
            output_a(D);
            PORTB = (display[decena]);  
            delay_ms(10);
            output_a(0);        
            //centena
            output_a(C);
            PORTB = (display[centena]);  
            delay_ms(10);
            output_a(0);        
         
        }
     }
```

Declare `numero` like `int16`, `unidad`, `decena` & `centena` like `int` out from main in beginning!

Answer (score 0):

Here is an implementation using interrupts to refresh the LED digits:

```
/*
 * File:   main.c
 * Author: dan1138
 * Target: PIC16F84A
 * Compiler: XC8 v2.45
 * IDE: MPLABX v6.15
 *
 * Created on January 19, 2024, 11:42 AM
 */

/* Define the system oscillator this code will setup */
#define _XTAL_FREQ (4000000ul)

#pragma config FOSC = XT        // Oscillator Selection bits (XT oscillator)
#pragma config WDTE = OFF       // Watchdog Timer (WDT disabled)
#pragma config PWRTE = ON       // Power-up Timer Enable bit (Power-up Timer is enabled)
#pragma config CP = OFF         // Code Protection bit (Code protection disabled)

#include <xc.h>
#include <stdint.h>

const char LEDDigit[] = 
{ 
  /*gfedcba          _   */
  0b01111110,   /*  | |  */
                /*  |_|  */
                /*       */
  0b00001100,   /*    |  */
                /*    |  */
                /*   _   */
  0b10110110,   /*   _|  */
                /*  |_   */
                /*   _   */
  0b10011110,   /*   _|  */
                /*   _|  */
                /*       */
  0b11001100,   /*  |_|  */
                /*    |  */
                /*   _   */
  0b11011010,   /*  |_   */
                /*   _|  */
                /*   _   */
  0b11111010,   /*  |_   */
                /*  |_|  */
                /*   _   */
  0b00001110,   /*    |  */
                /*    |  */
                /*   _   */
  0b11111110,   /*  |_|  */
                /*  |_|  */
                /*   _   */
  0b11001110,   /*  |_|  */
                /*    |  */
                /*   _   */
  0b11101110,   /*  |_|  */
                /*  | |  */
                /*       */
  0b11111000,   /*  |_   */
                /*  |_|  */
                /*   _   */
  0b01110010,   /*  |    */
                /*  |_   */
                /*       */
  0b10111100,   /*   _|  */
                /*  |_|  */
                /*   _   */
  0b11110010,   /*  |_   */
                /*  |_   */
                /*   _   */
  0b11100010,   /*  |_   */
                /*  |    */
                /*       */
  0b00000000,   /* blank */
                /*       */
};


volatile uint8_t Digit1Segments;
volatile uint8_t Digit2Segments;
volatile uint8_t Digit3Segments;

void __interrupt() ISR_handler(void)
{
    static uint8_t Timer0Ticks;
    
    if (TMR0IE && TMR0IF) {  /* TIMER0 asserts and interrupt every 1.024 milliseconds */
        TMR0IF=0;
        if ((Timer0Ticks++ & 0x0F) == 0) { /* every 16.384ms drive a new digit */
            PORTB &= ~0b11111110;   /* Turn off all segment drivers */
            if ((TRISA & 7) == 0b011) {
                TRISA |= 0b111;
                TRISA &= 0b110;    /* Drive digit 1 */
                PORTB |= Digit1Segments;
            }
            else if ((TRISA & 7) == 0b110) {
                TRISA |= 0b111;
                TRISA &= 0b101;     /* Drive digit 2 */
                PORTB |= Digit2Segments;
            }
            else {
                TRISA |= 0b111;
                TRISA &= 0b011;     /* Drive digit 3 */
                PORTB |= Digit3Segments;
            }
            PORTA |= 0b111;
        }
    }
}

void main(void) {
    uint16_t Count;
    /*
     * Initialize this PIC
     */
    INTCON = 0;
    __delay_ms(500);    /* Give ICSP device programming tool a chance to get the PICs attention */
    
    Digit1Segments = 0;
    Digit2Segments = 0;
    Digit3Segments = 0;
    TRISA = 0xFF;   /* PORTA bits 0,1,2 are digit drivers */
    TRISB = 0x01;   /* PORTB bits 7 to 1 are segment drivers */
    OPTION_REG = 0b11000001; /* TIMER0 clock = FOSC/4, prescale 1:4 */
    PORTA = 0;
    PORTB = 0;
    TMR0 = 0;
    TMR0IF = 0;
    TMR0IE = 1;
    GIE = 1;
    /*
     * This is the application loop.
     * 
     * It counts up one count about every second.
     */
    Count = 0;
    while(1)
    {
        Digit1Segments = LEDDigit[(Count      ) % 10];
        Digit2Segments = LEDDigit[(Count /  10) % 10];
        Digit3Segments = LEDDigit[(Count / 100) % 10];
        __delay_ms(1000);
        Count++;
    }
}
```